# DIV Image not being displayed

Tags: html, css

I think the path is correct for the background image, because that same path worked in the HTTML but I could be wrong.  Basically, the image is not being displayed.  Does anyone know why?

### HTML

```
<head>
<title>2013 YourFantasyFootball</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/css_reset.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mystyles.css" />
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
<!--<img src="images/final2.gif" class="stretch" alt="" />-->
<p>This is the first paragraph in the body of your new HTML file!</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

### CSS

```
body {
    /*width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
    position: fixed; 
    left: 0px; 
    top: 0px; */
    /*z-index: -1;*/ /* Ensure div tag stays behind content; -999 might work, too. */

    background-color:black;
}

.container {
    background-image:url('images/final2.gif');
    width:900px;
    height:2000px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
```

Comment: Create a jsfiddle at http://jsfiddle.net so that we can help you out

Comment: try ../images/final2.gif

Answer (score 5):

Use `"../"` to go back one directory and select the file as your CSS file is another folder.

So try this:

```
background-image:url('../images/final2.gif');
```

`../` in your CSS file means that go back one directory so then it will go to your root folder then it will look for the `images` folder then find the `final2.gif` and then your image will be displayed. It works in your HTML because you HTML file is already in the root folder so it doesn't need to go back one directory, it just directly finds out the `images` folder.

And as *@Lee Meador* said:

> So the URL in HTML is relative to the path of the HTML file and the URL in the CSS file is relative to the path of the CSS file.

That's absolutely correct.

Comment: So the URL in HTML is relative to the path of the HTML file and the URL in the CSS file is relative to the path of the CSS file.

Comment: @stack over try accepting answers this will attract other users to answer mroe on your questions.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because you are using a relative URL, so the path is relative to the file it is contained within.

In the first example that path is relative to the HTML file, so it can find the images folders. However, in your second example the path is relative to your CSS file, and because that is in a subfolder (css) it cannot find the images folder.

This should work:

```
background-image:url('../images/final2.gif');
```

Using `../` specifies the parent folder. Which is where your html file is, and more importantly, where the "images" folder is located.